# How to convert characters in a String to Unicode values greater than U+FFFF (UTF-32) like Mathematical Alphanumeric ?

Tags: javascript, unicode

## A String with "ABCabc" should be converted to ""

­­
That means, a string with normal letters should be transformed to a string with Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols)).
­

­

## Problem with Unicode grater than FFFF

##### This is working fine:

```
String.fromCharCode("A".codePointAt(0));
--> 'A'
```

##### But this fails:

```
String.fromCharCode("".codePointAt(0));
--> '풳'

String.fromCharCode("".codePointAt(0));
''
```

##### Therefor this fails too:

```
String.fromCharCode("A".codePointAt(0) + "".codePointAt(0));
--> '풳'

String.fromCharCode("a".codePointAt(0) + "".codePointAt(0));
''
```

­

How to convert the Unicode for letters to Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols?

Comment: You have to use UTF-16 *surrogate pair* codes.

Comment: Uh, use [`fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) together with `codePointAt`, `fromCharCode` corresponds to `charCodeAt`?

Comment: `.codePointAt` Converts a character into a number. `.fromCharCode` converts a number to a character. `String.fromCharCode("A".codePointAt(0) + "".codePointAt(0));` takes two characters, converts them to numbers, adds those numbers and then converts that number to a character. This is obviously not going to do anything useful (even after changing it to use matching functions).

Comment: `A` and `` do correlate in unicode, though. So you could do something like `const capDiff = "".codePointAt() - "A".codePointAt() ; let convertedChar = String.fromCodePoint("Z".codePointAt() + capDiff) ;`. (Lowercase will have a different offset.)

Comment: If your goal is to make your text look pretty then **do not do this** — Mathematical Symbols are not letters. They have different meanings. They will make your content inaccessible for lots of people (e.g. people using screen readers and search engines)

Comment: Quentin: My goal is to test whether I can make it more difficult for the ever-increasing automated censorship on the Internet to automatically evaluate texts.

Comment: @Inherent: no, there are standard tools to normalize unicode (in this case is compatibility), and it is always done if one need to compare strings. So there will not be help in such case, but it makes things more difficult for people with impaired vision (e.g. if they requires a reader: the reader do not need to compare text, but it look semantic: it is a symbol and not a part of a word).

Comment: In any case, check MDN: it has a lot of documentation, and usually there are comments on the function which works with UTF-32, or some wrapper for that. Javascript started with UCS-2 (so UTF-16 but if you treat code units as base unit and not code points). For compatibility JS must keep such old interface, and so it added often a UTF-32 interface.

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like this:

```js
const shiftStr = str => [...str].reduce((a, l) => a + String.fromCodePoint(119951 + l.charCodeAt(0) - 6 * (96 < l.charCodeAt(0))), '')

console.log(shiftStr("ABCabc"))
```

Comment: Wow, that's compact. Thank You Kosh!